# Ошибка при отправке писем Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, smtp

При отправке сообщений с сайта (из формы обратной связи) выскакивает ошибка 500.

```
local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.beget.com :stream_socket_client(): 
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:
wrong version number {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): 
Connection could not be established with host smtp.beget.com 
:stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number at
vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:261)
```

Настройки файла **.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.beget.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=smtp@secret.ru
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=smtp@secret.ru
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}
```

Настройка файла **config/mail.php**

```php
'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION',  ),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
```

Контролер **FeedBackMessage.php**

```php
 Mail::send('email', [
     'name' => $request->get('name'),
     'email' => $request->get('email'),
     'street' => $request->get('street'),
     'number' => $request->get('number'),
     'themes' => $request->get('themes'),
     'msg' => $request->get('msg')
       ],
        function ($message) {
          $message->from('smtp@secret.ru');
          $message->to('smtp@secret.ru')
           ->subject('Сообщение с сайта');
            }
    );
```

До вчерашнего вечера все было хорошо, но были настройки для YandexMail. Далее днем пришло сообщения от вышеупомянутых ям, что мол много спама, и ящик пока что будет в блоке.

Решил сменить настройки почты на те что предоставил хостинг, все данные вносил согласно инструкциям, но вот Laravel выдает 500 ошибку при отправке почты из формы.

Comment: `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION',  ),` эта строка даст unexpected characher.. Попробуйте без ssl -> порт 587 и `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),`. Кстати, с какой ОС запустить пытаетесь?

Comment: @InDevX, ubuntu 20.04. Добавил кавычки, но результат такой-же `500 | SERVER ERROR`

Comment: Попробуйте ещё auth_mode сменить `'auth_mode' => 'login'`. И хост `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),` => `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),`

Comment: @InDevX, Так же - без изменений `500`

Comment: а сама ошибка не поменялась? 500 это статус, в большинстве он говорит что где-то есть fatal error

Comment: @InDevX, Нет - ошибка 500, и лог такой-же.